# Count number of occurences for each distict item in a datacolumn

Tags: c#

I am using C# ConoleApplication.

I have ODBC DSN connection that i bring into Datatable.
Column One is "Account#".

Example:

Account#------------|

AA1-------------------|

AA1-------------------|

AA2-------------------|

AA3-------------------|

AA1-------------------|

AA4-------------------|

AA2-------------------|

I am trying to work out how to give the following result.
I would think it would be totaled into a new datatable but i cant make any code work that I have tried.

Account#------------|  Occurences

AA1-------------------|3

AA2-------------------|2

AA3-------------------|1

AA4-------------------|1

Please how can i do this?

Comment: Occurrences has 2 'r's ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable` and `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var accountGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("Account#"))
    .Select(grp => new { Account = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() });
```

If you need a new `DataTable`:

```
var tblAccCounts = new DataTable();
tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("Account#");
tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

foreach(var grp in accountGroups)
    tblAccCounts.Rows.Add(grp.Account, grp.Count);
```

Comment: up one for the anonymous type list

Comment: This is brilliant and I have used it for ages now, but I am having trouble now as the source contains mixed data some upper and some lower. This code wont group ignoring case. How to I make it or can I make it all uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

DataTable is a bit weird when it comes to LINQ, but it can be done. The key is casting the DataRowCollection returned by DataTable.Rows.

```
var results = DataTable.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>(0))
    .Select(g => new { Account = g.Key, Occurrences = g.Count()});
```

Getting the results into a new DataTable is a bit complicated, as you'll need to create the table manually.

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Account#", typeof(string)));
newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Occurrences", typeof(int)));

foreach(var result in results)
{
    var row = newTable.Rows.NewRow();
    row[0] = result.Account;
    row[1] = result.Occurrences;
    newTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

*edit: Tim's solution also works :)*

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but use linq it will make your life easier

```
using System.Linq;

dynamic amounts = dataTable
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(item => item.AccountNumber)
    .Select(list => new{ AccountNumber: list.Key, Amount: list.Count() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. Just tried it on my DB.

select account, count(account) from table group by account;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testClass tc = new testClass();
            DataTable dt = tc.getTestData();

            for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account No {0} Occurence {1}", dt.Rows[i]["ACCNO"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["Occurence"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    class testClass
    {
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }

        private SqlConnection Conn;

        private void TestConnect()
        {
            string strConn = "Data source = .\\SQLEXPRESS2012; Initial catalog = TEST; Integrated security = SSPI;";
            Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        }

        public DataTable getTestData()
        {
            TestConnect();
            string cmdStr = "SELECT ACCNO, COUNT(XYZ.ACCNO) AS 'Occurence' FROM XYZ GROUP BY ACCNO;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, Conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }

            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple and reliable solution

I think this is what you wanted.

**Example code**

```
// Create Results DataTable

DataTable ResultsDataTable = new DataTable();
ResultsDataTable.Columns.Add("Account#"); // Columns default to System.string
ResultsDataTable.Columns.Add("Occurances", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

ResultsDataTable.AcceptChanges(); //This asserts any changes to your table structure.

// Populate Results DataTable

foreach (DataRow SourceDataRow in SourceDataTable.Rows)
{
    string AccountNumber = SourceDataRow["Account#"].ToString();

    bool IsPresent = false;

    foreach(DataRow ResultsDataRow in ResultsDataTable.Rows)
    {
        if(ResultsDataRow["Account#"].ToString() == AccountNumber)
        {
            ResultsDataRow["Occurances"] = ((int)ResultsDataRow["Occurances"]) + 1; //Row exists for this account number, so increment the occurances value

            IsPresent = true;

            break;

        }

    }

    if (!IsPresent)
    { 
        // There isn't a row for this Account number, so create one and set it to one.

        DataRow NewResultsRow = ResultsDataTable.NewRow();

        NewResultsRow["Account#"] = AccountNumber;

        NewResultsRow["Occurances"] = 1;

        ResultsDataTable.Rows.Add(NewResultsRow);

        ResultsDataTable.AcceptChanges();

    }

}

ResultsDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

**Notes on this example**

I don't know what your source DataTable is called, so I called it SourceDataTable.

Similarly, I've created a results datatable called ResultsDataTable.

This is about twice as fast as the nearest Linq equivalent

This covers most of the common ways to manipulate DataTables, so it should stand you in good stead to solve similar problems on your own in future.

I hope it helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A best practice approach is certainly to adopt the Linq framework as shown by the other answers.

However, if you want a more "zero principles" approach that offers you a count of **every item** in your column, I would propose the following. Note that this method is actually a bit more flexible, as it returns a dictionary, or "map", of the count of **every item** in that column, not just the one you are looking for. All you will then need to do, is query the map for your specific item.

```
private DataTable dt;

...

private Dictionary<string, int> countColumnOccurances(int columnIndex)
{
    //Make a unique list of Items for the column of interest
    string indexName = dt.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName;
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    DataTable distinctColumnDT = view.ToTable(true, dt.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName);
    List<String> listOfDistinctItems = new List<String>();
    foreach (DataRow r in distinctColumnDT.Rows)
    {
        listOfDistinctItems.Add(r[indexName].ToString());
    }
    //Associate each of these items with a count
    var itemsAndTheirCount = new Dictionary<String, int>();
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var l in listOfDistinctItems)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (l == r[indexName].ToString())
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        itemsAndTheirCount.Add(l, count);
        count = 0;
    }
    return itemsAndTheirCount;
}
```

Verbosity and verbage included so you may follow the logic, however, you may easily reduce the line count.

Answer (score -1):

You are using SqlServer? If so you can do it on the bd like this:

```
SELECT Account#, Count(*) FROM [Table] GROUP BY Account#
```

Comment: Yes, but hes getting data from some DB if im not mistaken, and if im getting data from a DB id rather Count/Group/Sort on the DB then in c#